# pam_time.so configuration is ignored, how to debug it?

Tags: authentication, pam

I'm trying to use the `pam_time.so` module to restrict the times at which some users may use `sudo`. However, my configuration changes seem to have no effect. **How can I debug this issue? Is it possible for my distro to change the location for `/etc/security/time.conf`?**
The `pam.d/sudo` file already existed, and if I comment out other lines I can see the effect, but the `time.conf` file did not exist anywhere in `/etc`, so I might simply be modifying the wrong file.

Below is what I have attempted so far.

---

Here are the contents of `/etc/security/time.conf`:

```
sudo;*;*;!Al0830-1700
su;*;*;!Al0830-1700
```

And here are the contents of `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and `/etc/pam.d/su` (the default on my distro, plus the first line to load `pam_time.so`).

```
account required pam_time.so debug
account required pam_unix.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so  likeauth try_first_pass
auth required pam_deny.so
password requisite pam_unix.so nullok sha512
session required pam_env.so envfile=…
session required pam_unix.so
```

When I try to use `sudo /bin/sh`, `journalctl -f` prints:

```
août 09 13:53:15 nixos sudo[7454]:  georges : TTY=pts/6 ; PWD=/home/georges ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh
août 09 13:53:15 nixos sudo[7454]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

- The `debug` in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` seems to have no effect
- Some sources on the internet use `account requisite pam_time.so` instead of `required`, but it makes no difference for me
- `pamtester -v sudo root open_session` does not show any useful information (and succeeds), but `pamtester -v sudo root authenticate` rejects my password, and the `journalctl` log shows that, but the values in `time.conf` have no effect:

  ```
  août 09 13:56:03 nixos unix_chkpwd[7965]: check pass; user unknown
  août 09 13:56:03 nixos unix_chkpwd[7965]: password check failed for user (root)
  ```
- I tried removing the `auth sufficient pam_unix.so …` line, and sudo access gets prohibited without even trying a password, so I know changes in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` work. `pam_time.so` cannot be used as a `auth` module, however (the `journalctl` log complains about a missing symbol).
- I tried rebooting the machine, but the configuration is still ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies with two wildcards.

> `sudo;*;*;!Al0830-1700`

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/time.conf) it can be only used once: "*For these items the simple wildcard '*' may be used only once.*"

To circumvent this, you may use something like:

> `sudo;*;!root;!Al0830-1700`

This applies the rule to every user (except root).

**Edit**: Scratch that, it works on my system.
btw, you should test the account stack with `pamtester -v sudo username acct_mgmt`

Comment: So, you are saying your answer is wrong?